# Any idea to be able to make the character still continue the game until no heart left

Tags: javascript, unityscript

I am newbie I am making a 2d game in unity 3d my code for the character game over is this.. I can get the heart less one heart if game over but turn back to five again I just want to decrease heart whenever character die until it loss all the five heart

and my code for the heart is this...

```
function Start () {
    coins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coin");
    moveSpeed=10;
    anim=GetComponent(Animator);
    MainCode.Hearts = 5;
}

function Update () {

    transform.rotation.z=0;
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
         transform.position.y+=moveSpeed*Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if(transform.position.y<-5) {
         Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
         MainCode.Hearts -=1;
    }
    if (MainCode.Hearts <= 0){
         GameOver();
    }

}


var image : GUITexture;
var Image_01 : Texture2D;
var Image_02 : Texture2D;
var Image_03 : Texture2D;
var Image_04 : Texture2D;
var Image_05 : Texture2D;
var Image_06 : Texture2D;

function Update {
    if(MainCode.Hearts == 5){
         image.texture= Image_01;
    }
    if(MainCode.Hearts == 4){
        image.texture= Image_02;
    }
    if(MainCode.Hearts == 3){
        image.texture= Image_03;
    }
    if(MainCode.Hearts == 2){
         image.texture= Image_04;
    }
    if(MainCode.Hearts == 1){
        image.texture= Image_05;
    }
}
```

however its not working properly any help would be really much appreciated thank you in advance

Comment: So, a few issues.  First, your `GameOver()` code in the first section is subtracting a heart before what appears to be resetting the game.  That's not necessary.  But what calls `GameOver()`?  There should maybe be something in Update() that is like: `if (MainCode.Hearts <= 0) {GameOver();}`  There are some non-critical issues that might make your code easier to read as well.  Don't call things "Image_01" etc.  And if Image_01 has five hearts, why not call it `heartsImg5`? And the one that shows only 1 heart `heartsImg1`

Comment: #pragma strict
var image : GUITexture;
var Image_01 : Texture2D;
var Image_02 : Texture2D;
var Image_03 : Texture2D;
var Image_04 : Texture2D;
var Image_05 : Texture2D;
var Image_06 : Texture2D;

function Update () {
if(MainCode.Hearts == 5){
image.texture= heartimg5;

}
if(MainCode.Hearts == 4){
image.texture= heartimg4;
and so on...   then i remove the subtracting heart in the code game over and placed a code in my update

Comment: like this....y update  function Update () {

 transform.rotation.z=0;
 
    MainCode.Hearts ==5;

 if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
 

  transform.position.y+=moveSpeed*Time.deltaTime;
 
  
  }

 if(transform.position.y<-5){
     MainCode.Hearts -=1;
     else
     { (MainCode.Hearts <= 0)
  GameOver();
 }

} but its not working still

Comment: @aikachiqq Code in comments is hard to read. Please just update your question instead.

Comment: Also, please do not remove the code which was corrected by an answer. It invalidates the answer and makes it impossible to understand what's going on for an observer. Remember that you are not the only person who is supposed to learn from your question.

Comment: You realize you have 2 functions Update in your code?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Update()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) method is executed multiple times per second while your game is running. In the beginning of your update function you set `MainCode.Hearts = 5;`. That means whenever that variable is set to a different value it will be reset back to 5 shortly after.

You likely want to create a [`Start()`](http://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.unity3d.com%2FDocumentation%2FScriptReference%2FMonoBehaviour.Start.html) method and move that line there. The Start-method is called once when the game object it is attached to is created.

Note that reloading the scene with `Application.LoadLevel` also re-creates all objects which re-executes all their `Start`-methods. As a workaround you can either use a start-method on a game-object which is not affected by LoadLevel ([`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)) or reset the level by resetting all objects manually.

Comment: I placed my MainCode.Hearts = 5; in the start() however i want to resume the game if ever it decrease 1 heart still but it wouldnt let me

Comment: @aikachiqq I do not understand what you mean with "it wouldn't let you". Please describe properly what the intended behavior is and what behavior you witness instead.

Comment: I updated my code whenever the player died its life as heart decrease one and restart the game until the heart is 0 and gameover  howeve it wouldnt decrease one heart but restart the game

Comment: @aikachiqq Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your game logic should be

```
Init function
    Hearts count = 5;

Game loop
    For each frame
        update()
        draw()

update function
    if died
         Hearts count --;
    if Hearts count == 0
         GameOver();

draw function
    your drawing stuff
```

Then all you need to do is call the Init function at the beginning, then lauch the loop.

Beware that I just wrote peudo-code, don't try to copy-paste, try to undestand the underlying logic :)